# if statement with multiple string in Python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, find

I've this if statment that must check if this two string are present on `self.line.lower()` that can be ex: *123abc567* or *blaxyzbla*:

```
        if 'abc' or 'xyz' in self.line.lower():
            print ('Present')
        else:
            print ('Not Present')
```

why this return me ever true(Print Present), if the `self.line.lower()` doesn't contain the `abc` or `xyz` in the string?

I must use this to work:

```
     if self.line.lower().find('abc') != -1:
        print ('Present')
     elif self.line.lower().find('xyz') != -1:
        print ('Present')
     else:
        print ('Not Present')
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you had was equivalent to:

```
if 'abc' or ('xyz' in self.line.lower()):
```

Order of precedence table can be found in this Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html). At the bottom of the chart you will see `in` has higher precedence than `or` (or `and`) therefore `'xyz'` was checked to be in `self.line.lower()` and then that result was `or`'ed with `'abc'`. Since `'abc'` evaluates to a non-zero value the entire expression would always be true.

One way I can think of doing this *neatly* is as a nested `for in` that looks for the items in the target list against the string we are searching.

```
if any(x in line.lower() for x in ['abc', 'xyz']):
    print ('Present')
else:
    print ('Not Present')
```

`x in line.lower() for x in ['abc', 'xyz']` produces a generator that will return true or false for each element. You use `any` to figure out if any of the elements in the generated list are `true` meaning at least one of them was found. If you wanted to check if all of the items are found in the string you can replace `any` with `all`.

Comment: This work only if i find strict string 'abc' or 'xyz', but not work if i check presence on string: 123abc456 or blaxyzbla

Comment: You are correct. Even if we account for precedence it still isn't going to do what you want. I have provided a one liner that should do what you want.

Comment: thanks a lot, with this method works :)

Comment: Not a problem. I also added a bit about replacing 'any` with 'all' if you wanted to know if ALL the strings you were checking for were in the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'abc' or 'xyz' in self.line.lower():
```

is being broken into two different conditionals, which are then evaluated together with `or`.

- `'abc'`
- `'xyz' in self.line.lower()`

The first of the two will always evaluate as True, because it's not an empty string.

So you have `if True or 'xyz' in self.line.lower()` which will always evaluate to true.  For this reason, your code will always `print ('Present')` and never `print ('Not Present')`.

I think you'd like to use

```
if 'abc' in self.line.lower() or 'xyz' in self.line.lower():
    print('Present')
else:
    print('Not Present')
```